# Longtable overflowing with ESKDX

Tags: longtable

When I try to create a `longtable` with `\linewidth` width in portrait orientation it handles very strange.

[image: Longtable overflowing]

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,floatsection,equationsection,reduceheight=1mm,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
\usepackage{longtable, tabularx, lscape}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\newpage
Example is on the second page
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|}
\hline
TabularX\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|}
\caption{Table}\\
\hline
Head & Head & Head\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{End of table \thetable}\\
\hline
Head & Head & Head\\\hline
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Longtable & with & 3 cells \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\linewidth}|}
\caption{Tabletable}\\
\hline
Head\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{End of tabletable \thetable}\\
\hline
Head\\\hline
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Longtable with 1 cell \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

You can just [visit project page on Sagecloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/6974e31e-f88e-4dc5-a5ca-fd10acce0c48/files/example.tex)

Comment: can you reproduce the problem without the sagetex and other non standard files?

Comment: You're forgetting the intercolumn spaces

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done!

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{\linewidth}|}
```

makes a table `\linewidth+2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth` wide, you want

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
```

similarly

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|p{0.25\linewidth}|}
```

is too wide by 6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth